# How to exclude string using Regex?

Tags: regex

I have below data

`May 18 22:15:04 172.24.11.74 "abc","5","0",........`

I want to capture only abc it could be anything (abc,bcd, aaa or it can be empty ), so I want to ignore May 18 22:15:04 172.24.11.74 . Also after Immediate match it should stop .So in simple terms I want to match everything between first  "". Please help me to understand how I can achieve it . I tried following

`(?<=")([\w\s]+)(?=")`

It works fine only if first double quotes have some value . But when it is blank it moves further and capture next value in the double quotes . For example for below message it captures 5.

`May 18 22:15:04 172.24.11.74 "","5","0"`

I hope I am clear with my requirement .

Answer (score 1):

I think you were almost there.

If you make the group in the middle optional by adding a `?` behind it, it matches even if there's nothing between the double quotes:

`(?<=")([\w\s]+)?(?=")`

Alternatively you can match the middle part * times instead of + times which means one or more times and by this does not match if the part is empty:

`(?<=")([\w\s]*)(?=")`